# Resolve undefined symbol for shared libraries

Tags: c, shared-libraries

In a C-program, I want to add specific modules as shared-libraries using `dlopen`.

Using `dlopen` with  `RTLD_LAZY` (using `RTLD_NOW` directly fails probably due to the reason below) and `dlsym` I can create the handle to the actual function that I want to call. After calling the function, I get the error

```
program: symbol lookup error: file.so: undefined symbol: createExpressionNumber
```

The function `createExpressionNumber` is a function of the program. The shared library is compiled by

```
gcc -fPIC -c ...
```

and linked by

```
gcc -shared ...
```

It seems, that symbols are not resolved when linking as shared lib (which makes sense) but that the symbols are not provided by my program when opening the lib.

Is there any way to provide the functions of my program to the loaded shared lib or do I need to extract all functions from my program that are used by the shared lib as seperate shared lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [**`-rdynamic`**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) on your main program link line. That would:

> `Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of "dlopen" or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program.`

i.e. would allow dynamically-loaded shared library to lookup symbols of the main executable.